# What is a Checkmate Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Checkmate Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Checkmate Word™ | Not Checkmate Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABBEY | MONASTERY |
| RANK | FILE |
| BROOK | STREAM |
| QUARRY | MINE |
| IN | OUT |
| ERROR | MISTAKE |
| REQUIRE | REQUEST |
| KINE | COWS |
| BARRIER | OBSTACLE |
| BANK | MONEY |
| BONE | SKULL |
| REAR | FRONT |
| ROOK | PAWN |
| QUEEN | BISHOP |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Checkmate Word™, Not Checkmate Word™
ABBEY,MONASTERY
RANK,FILE
BROOK,STREAM
QUARRY,MINE
IN,OUT
ERROR,MISTAKE
REQUIRE,REQUEST
KINE,COWS
BARRIER,OBSTACLE
BANK,MONEY
BONE,SKULL
REAR,FRONT
ROOK,PAWN
QUEEN,BISHOP
```

*Note: This is my first puzzle of this kind, so it may not be well-worked*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A word is a Checkmate word if

> The majority of the consonants in the word are from the set $B,R,K,N,Q$ - the letters representing the major chess pieces.

Or even more specifically

> If we count $Y$ as a vowel (semi-vowel) then all of the consonants in the word are from this set.

Comment: Great! Actually, my intention was rot13(vapyhqr C (sbe cnja) nf na npprcgrq pbafbanag gbb), but I forgot to include at least one example for it. It was my fault, so accepting this.